# How the '\n' symbol works in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I always thought that in order to get a new line in my standard output I need to add '\n' inside my print statement. But recently I came across the following expression:

```
print("Hello"),'\n',print("World")
```

Which works just like:

```
print("Hello\nWorld")
```

Can someone explain how the '\n' works outside the print function and yet my standard output knows to get a new line?
Also what is the meaning of the comma symbols in the first expression which are also outside the print function?

Comment: That's a tuple! It is not equivalent to `print("Hello\nWorld")`

Comment: This creates a tuple (the commas do it, parentheses are not necessary) containing the return value of `print('Hello')`, which is None, a `'\n'`, and None again. While building it, you print 'Hello', then print 'World', and they get printed as usual with final newlines. The `'\n'` in the middle is useless and irrelevant. And this all is a piece of ugliness - where did you encounter that?

Comment: Thierry, spot-on. You should post this as actual answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
print('Hello'),'\n',print('World')
```

and

```
print('Hello\nWorld')
```

are not equivalent.

The first is an expression which returns a tuple of `(NoneType, str, NoneType)` (because `\n` is a string and the `print` function returns `None`, which has type `NoneType`). However, this expression has the side effect of also printing first `Hello` then `World` to stdout. Since print, by default, puts a newline at the end of each invocation, this will appear as

```
Hello
World
```

in stdout.

The second is simply an expression that prints `Hello\nWorld` to stdout, which (since `\n` is the newline character) also appears as

```
Hello
World
```

in stdout.

At a REPL (or jupyter notebook, or similar), you will get:

```
>>> print('Hello'),'\n',print('World')
Hello
World
(None, '\n', None)
>>> print('Hello\nWorld')
Hello
World
```

this is because default behaviour is for the REPL to print the value that your expression evaluates to, unless that value is `None`. So in the first case it executes the two `print` functions (getting `Hello\nWorld` on stdout) then prints the expression's value, the tuple `(None, '\n', None)`.

Comment: Even `print("Hello"), print("World")` will also print like the 1st example. It creates a tuple with two values. That `\n` is redundant if developer only wants to print. Because new line while printing is not coming from that `\n`, but it is inserted by the 1st `print`. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

on my jupyter-notebook I get:

```
Hello
World
(None, '\n', None)
```

so `print("Hello"),'\n',print("World")` it is not the same as `print("Hello\nWorld")`

Comment: The third line there is a result of executing in a REPL; in a script, the net effect would be the same (the `tuple` would be silently discarded), it would just be less efficient than a single `print("Hello\nWorld")` (and the `, "\n"` part is completely unnecessary/ignored).